# Moving an assembly/project to a different directory causes all references to lose their paths

Tags: visual-studio

I am currently going through an issue trying to move a project's folder to a different directory and loading it back on my solution.

Currently I have this directory:

> \Visual Studio 2013\Projects\

Inside of that I have 2 folders:

> AssemblyToMoveFolder
>
> SvenLion (Source Control)

My Main Project's solution is already in my source control:

> SvenLion\src\

With the folders:

> MainAssemblyFolder
>
> DLLAssemblyFolder
>
> Project.sln

Note that the project works fine the way it is. I have all 3 assemblies (AssemblyToMoveFolder, MainAssemblyFolder, DLLAssemblyFolder), loaded in the solution, it compiles fine and such.

Now the problem is: I want to move "AssemblyToMoveFolder" inside my source control's src folder so all assembly folders are under the same directory (SvenLion\src). However, when I tried to move it, it gave all my references yellow triangles and the "Path" under all of them are blank.

[image: References] [image: Path]

Steps I took:

1) Removed my AssemblyToMove.csproj from my sln.

2) Copied the folder and pasted it inside the SvenLion\src\ folder.

3) Re-added the AssemblyToMove.csproj from the copy to the sln.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is there is a "Project Reference" or a "File Reference", you need to add it as a project reference.

The add reference dialog has "projects" and a "Browse" tab on the left side.

But in general, moving things around may require you to rework some references.
In my opinion VS tries to fix them, but badly.

Comment: I don't need to add it as a project reference. That's not the issue. You can easily reproduce this issue by creating a solution with 2 projects. Move one of the project folders to a different directory and try to re-add the project to the solution. Also your answer is unclear and belongs on the comment section as it does not directly attempts to answer the question.